# Import 3D model in Visual Studio 2010(WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, opengl, 3d-modelling

I work on a project in VS2010(WPF aplication) for 3D game, i use Visual C# with OpenGL and GLControl, and i need help about importing 3D models.
Google search didn't help much, i need more things to know about import 3D models in these technologies.

Answer (score 1):

OpenGl is not a scene graph, and it will not load models for you. You need to load the model separately and then pass the vertex/normal/texture/index information to opengl using either vertex buffers/index buffers, or using the fixed function pipeline if that is the way you are going.

Other than that, we can not help you since this is such a general question, and each model format is loaded differently.

Comment: I know that i have to transform  model format in XAML code, after that, so how can i play(rotate, translate) with 3D model using OpenGl

Comment: @IlijaZdravkov: There is no best model format for OpenGL, because OpenGL is completely format agnostic. You choose the format based on your specific needs.

Comment: If you don't know what I meant with vertex buffers/index buffers, then you need to go get a beginner tutorial and slowly work your way up to the point where you can render a model.

Answer (score 0):

Check out ZAM3D and Microsoft Expression Designer, you can easily import and export models that you can directly use in xaml

Regarding rotate/translate transform, there is support built into WPF and you don't need open gl if you are using WPF, I would highly recommend you to install Expression Blend and use animation/camera-control to achieve the same.